# AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'field'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am still learning scrapy and has made a spider. And i keep getting this error "**AttributeError: module 'scrapy' has no attribute 'field**'"

This is my items.py:

```
import scrapy


class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
      text = scrapy.field()
      author = scrapy.field()
      tags = scrapy.field()
```

And this is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from testing.items import QuoteItem

class GoodReadspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "goodreads"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes?page=1'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.selector.xpath("//div[@class='quote']"):
            loader = ItemLoader(item = QuoteItem, selector = quote, response = response)
            loader.add_xpath('text', ".//div[@class='quoteText']/text()[1]")
            loader.add_xpath('author', ".//div[@class='quoteText']/child::a")
            loader.add_xpath('tags', ".//div[@class='greyText smallText left']/a")
            yield loader.load_item()

        next_page=response.selector.xpath("//a[@class='next_page']/@href").extract_first()

        if next_page is not None:
            next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: try using `scrapy["field"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capitalise `field` (to `Field`):

```
import scrapy
class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
```